# ng-if to check a variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do this

```
{% if collection %}
   <tr ng-repeat="items in collection">
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
   </tr>
 {% else %}
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">No items in collection</td>
   </tr>
 {% endif %}
```

but I am getting an error saying collection variable is not defined. What's the correct syntax to do that?

Comment: I believe you are getting your scripting environments mixed up. `{% ... %}` is probably used by a Liquid templating engine. So you would need to define `collection` in the model used by Liquid. That will be separate from the `collection` defined in the AngularJS scope.

Comment: Are you population that variable using some kind of async request? If yes try to populate your variable asynchronously.

Comment: yes, collection is a result from an API call.
any alternative method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet

```
<tbody ng-if="collection.length > 0">
   <tr ng-repeat="items in collection">
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-if="!collection || collection.length==0">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">No items in collection</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping it all in angular logic

```
<tbody ng-if="collection">
   <tr ng-repeat="items in collection">
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-if="!collection || collection.length==0">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">No items in collection</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```